# Special unitary group simply connected?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-groups

Let $C'\rightarrow C$ be a double cover of smooth projective curves over $\mathbb C$. Let $K'/K$ the corresponding function fields extension. Denote by $\tau$ the Galois involution on $K'$. Let $SU(K')$ be the special unitary group defined by matrices $A\in SL(K')$ such that $$\tau(A)=\;^tA^{-1}$$ where the RHS is the inverse transpose matrix.

> > Is SU(K') simply connected?

Comment: This is a form of $SL_n$, so it's simply connected, if I don't miss something.

Comment: @YCor: How do you see that?

Comment: You have to perform the case when $K'=K\times K$ with the flip involution.

Comment: this is not a field!

Comment: Yes but it's the way it works... this is precisely why the notion of étale algebra is better than that of field extensions: it passes to extensions of scalars.